# Moving data to HBASE using Pig

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-pig, bigdata

I tried moving 851 data in my **hbase** for that i created hbase using below command

```
create 'customers', 'customers_data'
```

i moved the files using **pig** script. My pig script is

```
STOCK_A = LOAD '/user/cloudera/xxx' USING PigStorage('|');
data = FILTER STOCK_A BY ( $0 matches '.*MH.*');
MH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE $1, $3, $4;
STORE MH_DATA into 'hbase://customers' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('customers_data:firstname, customers_data:lastname, customers_data:age');
```

i got 851 data using my pig command. My data is

```
    (aman,george,22)
    (aman,george,22)
    (aman,george,22)
     .
     .
     .
     .
     .
    851
```

but when i try to put this data in hbase using below command

```
PIG_CLASSPATH=/usr/lib/hbase/hbase.jar:/usr/lib/zookeeper/zookeeper-3.4.5-cdh4.4.0.jar /usr/bin/pig /home/cloudera/remot/pighl7
```

data that is getting stored in HBASE is

```
ROW                                         COLUMN+CELL                                                                                                                 
 \xB5~\x5C&                                 column=customers_data:firstname, timestamp=1478700582076, value=george
 \xB5~\x5C&                                 column=customers_data:lastname, timestamp=1478700582076, value=22
```

I cant find my 851 records as well as the third parameter. I don't know what i am doing wrong.
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a lot of research and trail and error when i changed the **row key** from name to timestamp i solved my problem, As i am using using row key which is having same name as of others it always updates it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have missed giving alias in the generate statement (for safer side i have casted your tuples into chararray)

also at the end give name for you store relation

**TRY:**

```
MH_DATA = FOREACH data GENERATE (chararray)$1 AS firstname , (chararray)$3 AS lastname, (chararray)$4 AS age;

STORE_IN_HBASE = STORE MH_DATA into 'hbase://customers' USING org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.hbase.HBaseStorage('customers_data:firstname, customers_data:lastname, customers_data:age');
```

for more information follow this link: 
https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.14.0/api/org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/hbase/HBaseStorage.html

Comment: i tried your approach but i am only getting one row in my HBASE. In my logs i can see `851 items stored in customers`